# how to insert the meijerG function in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to insert the maijerG function in mathematica but i'm facing a problem..

this is the function that i want it in the meigerG function formula:

```
Exp[-s*x]
```

where x is the variable.

Comment: Might be some help here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html  Download the Mathematica notebook for syntax examples.

Comment: see here too, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeijerG.html , but note i'm pretty sure if you figure out the `MeijerG` expression that yields `Exp` it will just auto simplify for you, so rather pointless.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function#Representation_of_other_functions_in_terms_of_the_G-function